# Android. Run ui operations in onPostExecute when the fragment is paused

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous

I'm using a bunch of asynchronous tasks in my app and i want to run Ui operations in onPostExecute. 
I generally display a spinner while the asynchronous task is running and when it finishes i want to remove the spinner and either change the Ui or launch a new fragment.

I'm running into a problem when the app is not in the foreground when the asynchronous task finishes. I've been handling the error by checking if the fragment is paused and if it's paused i have a boolean wasPaused that i check in onResume to run the onPostExecute code but there must be a simpler way.

in onPostExecute

```
if (!isPaused) {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    } else {
    wasPaused= true;
}
```

and then onResume

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isPaused = false;
    if (wasPaused) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        wasPaused= false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update the UI of or launch a fragment from a background activity as the activity is paused (`onPause()` called). What you did is the right thing.

Comment: This seems a bit clumsy and a lot of work since i have so many async tasks.
Is there no better and easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know what your exact intentions are, but there's no use updating the UI when the activity is in the background. The UI matters only when the user sees it, so onResume() is the right place for you.